# Lucene - Token filter that access different field

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to create my own implementation of StopFilter that will choose the terms according to some other field.

Is there a way to access from a TokenFilter to the Document and then to some other field?

(I was thinking to use UpdateRequestProcessor to notify my TokenFilter about the state but I didn't find nice way to do it)

Thanks,
Benny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Token Filter does not have access to other fields. Only its own. On the other hand, UpdateRequestProcessor has access to all of the fields of the current document.

Why don't you use UpdateRequestProcessor and generate the tokens separated by some unique value. Then, just use basic Tokenizer to break on that and you have your filtered values.

Comment: The problem with UpdateRequestProcessor is that it actually changes the field and I want that the original value will be stored there.

Comment: Can you do the stored tokens in a cloned field, which is index-only. Then you have that field in the eDisMax instead of the original one.

Comment: In this case, I will need to search using the cloned field and the original one should be indexed="false". right?

Comment: Sure. You can search your heavily annotated/processed field but return the original field to the client. Or you search both but with different boosts, if the original form is also useful (e.g. on 'full-text' match).